# How to restrict findobj to only find object in gui being currently created?

Tags: matlab

I have two guis which are exact copies of each other.

However only some of the functionality is used in each gui. I basically saved a monolithic gui in GUIDE under two different names.

I am dividing up the monolith into subguis, each with the same fig file but saved in GUIDE with different names.

SubguiA and subguiB are launched from two buttons on a parent gui. In each subgui there is a usercontrol(a panel) which has 'UserData' set to 3005.I run subguiA from button 1. I run subguiB from button2 and step in  and ask for hpanel = findobj('UserData',3005) from within the CreateFcn of one of the textboxes on the subguiB. I get back hpanel as 2x1 double because it finds two such panels in memory. I get that.

So then when I go to set the userdata of the textbox using hpanel as 'Parent', the app crashes because hpanel is supposed to be 1x1. I thought I would use the handle of the subguiB in findobj so that is specifically restricts findobj to subguiB. However when the CreateFcn of the textbox on subguiB is being run, it does not yet have the hObject of the entire subguiB. The hObject of the entire subguiB is available from the OpeningFcn of the subguiB, which runs only after the CreateFcns of all the usercontrols on it have executed.

So the question is: how do I restrict findObj to finding the object only in subguiB( which is currently being created?).
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try another function:

```
findall(handle_list,'property','value',...)
```

here you can use a handle as the parent you want to search for objects with properties... Still you have to make sure to get the right object. Probably giving an unique name would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You could try another method of sharing resources so that you do not have this issue. In the Mathworks file exchange site there is an object oriented class called a Singleton (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24911-design-pattern-singleton-creational), which you can use to build a custom subclass to allow the exchange of important information and abstract the GUI interface details.

The point of a singleton is that you are guaranteed that there is only one in any program, thus you can store state information in that object and be able to access it from anywhere. No searching required.

When each GUI calls its CreateFcn it acquires the instance handle for the singleton subclass you created, and sets the GUI[A,B] window handle attribute so that the other GUI will have direct access to it via that same singleton. You can then build a messaging system to exchange or copy values across GUI's or orchestrate advanced coordination capabilities into your overall App. This is a great paradigm for any functionality where different parts of your App need to communicate such as allowing external Matlab scripts to interact with your GUI for batch type processing. Example, one GUI button callback can invoke a method in the singleton object to cause the second GUI to pop up and display and then populate that GUI with all the latest data context from the first GUI just entered, without that first GUI even knowing anything about the internals of the second GUI. If a GUI's controls change only the singleton need know about the internals of those changes.

Comment: That's very interesting, Steve! Appreciate your help.